# Produce a Hash String of Fixed Length

Tags: java

I would like to produce a hashed string of fixed length. I am using the [MessageDigest API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) for this. I noticed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest-byte:A-int-int-) function in the API but it returns an integer not a byte array.

When I tried to use this overloaded digest method, I get either a java.security.DigestException: Length must be at least 32 for SHA-256 digests or Output buffer too small for specified offset and length.

Can somebody give an example of how to produce a hash value of fixed length please?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It could also help if you edit your question and add the code which is not working.

Comment: In case you want something shorter, use the first or last n bytes from the digest you get back from the API.

Comment: the documentation of the method (link you posted) clearly states "*buf - output buffer for the computed digest*", the integer returned is just the byte count. You must pass a big enough byte array (empty) that will be filled by the method. And there are other methods available, like `digest`

Comment: Please also post the code which you tried and is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) `DigestUtils` to generate hex representation of a hash. There are a few  algorithms available:

- [`DigestUtils.sha1Hex()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha1Hex-java.lang.String-)
- [`DigestUtils.md5Hex()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex-java.lang.String-)

e.g.

```
String input = "Hello World";
String sha1 = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(input);
System.out.println(sha1); // 0a4d55a8d778e5022fab701977c5d840bbc486d0
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class TestA {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hashBytes(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    }

    public static byte[] hashBytes(byte [] bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(bytes);
        return md.digest();
    }
}
```

`SHA-256` can of course be used instead of `SHA-1`